# Must ViewPagers have a unique id within their Activity? (If they're backed by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity with two ViewPagers both working with a [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). But when the ViewPagers have no id, or both have the same id, they will not work correctly.

---

Activity layout (`activity.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

       <include layout="@layout/merge_pager" />

     </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/merge_pager" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Merge layout (`merge_pager.xml`):

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</merge>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    FrameLayout frame1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame1);
    FrameLayout frame2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame2);

    ViewPager vp1 = (ViewPager) frame1.getChildAt(0);
    ViewPager vp2 = (ViewPager) frame2.getChildAt(0);

    if (vp1 == null | vp2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    vp1.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    vp2.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

private class ColorAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ColorAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new ColorFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}

public static class ColorFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
        Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(randomColor());
        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        return tv;
    }

public static int randomColor() {
    return Color.rgb(random255(), random255(), random255());
}

public static int random255() {
    return
            (int) (Math.random() * (double) 255);
}
```

Using this code, the second ViewPager won't work. I suspected it might be due to clashing ids (`R.id.view_pager`), so I removed the id from the merge file. However, this results in a fatal exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
```

What is up with this?

Comment: 0xffffffff is -1 and it's the same as `NO_ID`. What was the problem you faced before removing the id?

Comment: The second `ViewPager` will show up, and will be scrollable (I can see the blue 'overflow' stuff if I scroll to the left, and it will even instantiate the colored Fragments, but it won't show the Fragments: I only see white background. However, the top `ViewPager` *does* work correctly. I suspect this is due to a bug / undocumented constraint because the two ViewPagers have the same id. Maybe the FragmentManager inserts fragments from the second ViewPager into the first ViewPager?

Comment: BTW, `frame1.findViewById(R.id.view_pager)` it is cleaner than `frame1.getChildAt(0)`. And also, with `include` you don't need `merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html):

> When using FragmentPagerAdapter the host ViewPager must have a valid ID set.

So at least it's documented that the adapter won't work without an id for its pager. I suppose you can then take 'valid' to mean 'unique in the activity view hierarchy'.

Comment: FYI, you can override the id in the `include` tag.